# BoxLayout doesn't respect glue when JLabel contains HTML

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel, boxlayout

I have a component I've written that uses BoxLayout to layout some JLabels horizontally, followed by glue (I'd like the JLabels' width to remain fixed). For example:

[image]

I need to add two lines of text to each JLabel, so I'm using a bit of HTML. As soon as I added the HTML, the BoxLayout stopped respecting the glue. I get something like:

[image]

I can get around this by specifying that the maximum size should be equal to the preferred size (specifying preferred size has no effect). Is this the correct approach? Is there some explanation for why glue seems to be ignored when there's HTML in my JLabels?

The MWE:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LabelBreak extends JFrame {

JPanel panel;

public LabelBreak() {
    setTitle("Frame");
    panel = new MyPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
    add(panel);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new LabelBreak();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}

private static class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private MyPanel() {
        super();
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        header.setLayout(new BoxLayout(header, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        //JLabel label = new JLabel("One");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>One<br>is<br>the<br>loneliest<br>number</html>");
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
        header.add(label);
        label = new JLabel("Two");
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
        header.add(label);
        header.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        this.add(header);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `Is there some explanation for why glue seems to be ignored when there's HTML in my JLabels?` - it looks like the calculation for the maximum size is different for HTML vs regular text. `I can get around this by specifying that the maximum size should be equal to the preferred size` - I would override the `getMaximumSize()` method to simply return the `getPreferredSize()` value. This way if you change the HTML it will still work.

Comment: In this particular case, the label text should be treated as final, so it doesn't matter if I just `setMaximumSize()`, but I feel like overriding `getMaximumSize()` is more future-proof anyway. And you're right: if maximum size isn't explicitly set, regular text just uses the preferred as the maximum, whereas for HTML the max width is essentially set to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (involving a call to `BasicHTML.getMaximumSpan()`)

Comment: @camickr Care to rephrase your comment as an answer?

Comment: `specifying preferred size has no effect` Just for future reference note that BoxLayout doesn't fully honor the preferredSize property: X_AXIS–honors preferred width, Y_AXIS–honors preferred height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some explanation for why glue seems to be ignored when there's HTML in my JLabels?

A BoxLayout will respect the maximum size (and minimum size) for components.

For normal text the maximum size would be the preferred size of the component, so the glue works as expected.

It looks like the calculation for the maximum size is different for HTML vs regular text.

> I can get around this by specifying that the maximum size should be equal to the preferred size

Yes, this is a reasonable approach, but I would override the `getMaximumSize()` method to simply return the `getPreferredSize()` value.

```
@Override
public Dimension getMaximumSize()
{
    return getPreferredSize();
}
```

This way if you change the HTML it will still work.

Comment: There's also a `Component.isMaximumSizeSet()` method that I might chuck in there if I wanted to leave open the possibility of setting the maximum size, something like `if (isMaximumSizeSet()) return super.getMaximumSize(); ...`

Answer (score 0):

`BoxLayout` respects maximum size of `JLabel` so you have to set it.

To control width between two labels you can use `Box.createHorizontalStrut(width)`.

Note that two labels are centered in `header`. I would use GridLayout to place components in one row with different space between columns.

```
private MyPanel() {
            super();
            this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            JPanel header = new JPanel();
            header.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4,20,0));
            // JLabel label = new JLabel("One");
            JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>One<br>is<br>the<br>loneliest<br>number</html>");
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
            label.setMaximumSize(label.getPreferredSize());
            header.add(label);
//          header.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
            label = new JLabel("Two");
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
            header.add(label);
            // header.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
            this.add(header);
        }
```